# MongoDB on Amazon EC2 - Configuring Mongo Client for Php

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, amazon-ec2, yii2

I am pretty new to Amazon EC2.

I followed the instructions given in mongodb official site for installing mongodb on Amazon Linux. I have a Yii-2(basic) project to host on my amazon Linux server. mongoDB is already installed in the and even I Imported some dumps over there. But when i run the project

> Class 'MongoClient' not found

How can I configure mongodb on amazone linux?
(now when i do sudo service mongod restart it is showing FAILED)

I installed mongodb using yum.

> PHP version 5.6
>   Amazon Linux

these are my configuration. I am sure I am using latest versions since it is a fresh installation. Please help me out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message it seems that you haven't installed the [PHP Mongo Driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/) in your server.

To check if you have it, try a `php_info()` and check if the entry "mongo" is present

If it's not present install it using the instructions found in the link above, or check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php)